# SharePoint 2013 Primary LookupField Shows ID when Set to ReadOnly

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint list that has some read only columns that is populated by workflow and I notice that if the read only column is a lookup field, it will show the ID in datasheet and display view.

So it looks like this: 1;#Text Content

I set the field to readonly by doing this:

field.ReadOnlyField = true;

Is there anyway to get rid of the ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a JSLink script to the field.

See this article: [Learning SharePoint](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/add-task-status-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js-link/).  Instead of modifying the webpart properties, I would just use the powershell to change the JSLink property of the field object instead.